# OpenCV Android(Java) --- Extract frames from MP4 file

Tags: android, opencv, javacv

I am trying to read an MP4 file in OpenCV Java on Android Studio but having no success. I create a VideoCapture object and pass the video as the argument to it but the videoCapture.read() method always returns false. I know that the file exists at that path because I am able to use FFmpeg and MediaExtractor libraries to read the video at that path but IDK why OpenCV never succeeds. Also, I am able to process the same video file using OpenCV in Python.

Here's a code snippet:

```
VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture(filePath);
            if(camera.read(imageMat)){
                System.out.println("read");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("not read");
            }
```

ImageMat is the matrix I want to read my video frames into.

I would really appreciate if anyone has any suggestions/ resources on how to read a video file using OpenCV in Java/Android Studio.

Comment: Try to use FFmpegFrameGrabber from [JavaCV](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/) instead. It has better support for files.

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV doesn't support .mp4 video format. If you want to use OpenCV then please use the .avi video format.

For more information you can refer to this medium post :
[blog](https://medium.com/@misaeljonathan17/frame-extraction-from-video-file-on-java-android-48aa9c71b97d)